# How to build libc++ with pstl support?

Tags: build, clang, llvm

I'm tring to build a standalone clang toolchain but libcxx doesn't support pstl now.

```bash
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G "Ninja" \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
  -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=lld \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld;lldb;libc" \
  -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=Native \
  -DCLANG_ENABLE_BOOTSTRAP=ON \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ \
  -DCLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="compiler-rt;libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;pstl" \
  -DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
  -DLIBCXXABI_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
  -DLIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER=YES \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld;lldb" \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_LLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="compiler-rt;libc;libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;pstl" \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_CLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_CLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_LIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_LIBCXXABI_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_LIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER=YES \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_LLVM_USE_LINKER=lld \
  -DLIBUNWIND_USE_COMPILER_RT=Yes \
  -DBOOTSTRAP_LIBUNWIND_USE_COMPILER_RT=Yes \
  ../src/llvm
ninja 
ninja stage2
```

But it always show me:

```bash
-- Could not find ParallelSTL, libc++abi will not attempt to use it but the build may fail if the libc++ in use needs it to be available.
-- Parallel STL uses the serial backend
```

How could I build libc++ with pstl support?

Comment: This bug has been fixed in llvm trunk after May 1st.

Comment: Is `pstl` really an option for `LLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES`? I thought it was only for `LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS`.

Comment: It should be. At least they did...

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out myself. I'm running your version now with addition of two lines:

-DLIBCXX_ENABLE_PARALLEL_ALGORITHMS=YES 
-DPSTL_PARALLEL_BACKEND="tbb" \

I'll let you know if it works...

Comment: Don'y try it. LLVM Team said this's a bug: https://reviews.llvm.org/D141779

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past the PSTL not found by first installing PSTL into the main build folder, but then it tripped up on something else. What I'm trying now is installing PSTL into libcxx/ folder. Here's my shell script I'm trying:

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -e

cd ~/Code/llvm-project
source env_llvm.sh
git pull

rm -f build-clang/CMakeCache.txt 2> /dev/null
rm -f build-pstl/CMakeCache.txt 2> /dev/null

mkdir -p build-clang 2> /dev/null
mkdir -p build-pstl 2> /dev/null

cd build-pstl
cmake -DPSTL_PARALLEL_BACKEND="tbb" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="~/Code/llvm-project/libcxx" ../pstl
make install-pstl
cd ..

cd build-clang
#   -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;lld;lldb;pstl;libclc" \
#   -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi;compiler-rt;libunwind" \
#   -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
#   -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=lld \
#   -DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ \
#   -DCLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt \
#   -DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
#   -DLIBCXXABI_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
#   -DLIBUNWIND_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
#   -DLIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER=YES \
#   -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=Native \

cmake \
    -G "Unix Makefiles" \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local" \
    -DLLDB_USE_SYSTEM_DEBUGSERVER=YES \
    \
    -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 \
    -DLLVM_RUNTIME_TARGETS=X86 \
    -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64" \
    -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT="$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)" \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/Users/martin/Code/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" \
    -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/cmake;~/Code/llvm-project/build-clang/lib/cmake" \
    \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" \
    -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi;libunwind;compiler-rt;pstl" \
    \
    -DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ \
    -DCLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt \
    -DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
    -DLIBCXXABI_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
    -DLIBUNWIND_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES \
    -DLIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER=YES \
    \
    -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_STATIC=YES \
    -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED=YES \
    -DLIBCXXABI_ENABLE_STATIC=YES \
    -DLIBCXXABI_ENABLE_SHARED=YES \
    -DLIBUNWIND_ENABLE_STATIC=YES \
    -DLIBUNWIND_ENABLE_SHARED=YES \
    \
    -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_PARALLEL_ALGORITHMS=YES \
    -DPSTL_PARALLEL_BACKEND="tbb" \
    \
    -DLLVM_INCLUDE_DOCS=NO \
    -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=NO \
    -DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=NO \
    -DLLVM_INCLUDE_BENCHMARKS=NO \
    \
    -DLLVM_INSTALL_TOOLCHAIN_ONLY=YES \
    -DLLVM_CREATE_XCODE_TOOLCHAIN=YES \
    \
    ../llvm

# echo
# read -s -k '?Press any key to build. CTRL-C to exit...'

nice -n 20 make -j $(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)

echo
read -s -k '?Press any key to install. CTRL-C to exit...'

make install
mv -f install_manifest.txt install_manifest.clang.txt
make install-xcode-toolchain
mv -f install_manifest.txt install_manifest.xcode.txt
make package
```

Comment: It's because it's a  llvm bug.

Comment: Agreed. I wonder when it will get addressed. I remember being able to do this on version 14 or 15 but it's been a while...

Comment: currently I'm able to get this working with OneDpl/TBB from Intel when compiling on Mac OS; haven't tried Linux in a long time and VS 2022 has full support already.

Comment: See this, reviews.llvm.org/D141779